# LXD: The "default" storage pool doesn't exist

Tags: lxd

I am getting the following error while I am trying to edit default lxc profile:

> The "default" storage pool doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/snap/bin/lxd init
```

or

```
lxd init
```

solved the issue, but select yes for following:

```
Do you want to configure a new storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]:
```

Then you can confirm with the following command and the output:

```
/snap/bin/lxc storage list

+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
|  NAME   | DESCRIPTION | DRIVER |                   SOURCE                   | USED BY |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
| default |             | zfs    | /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img | 1       |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Following [this](https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/user-manual) document will help.